# GNOME Mag jumps to focus

Tags: 16.04, gnome, accessibility

Just installed Ubuntu 16.04 with the GNOME Desktop. I use the built-in magnifier and noticed that it's now jumping to the text input focus, which results in a lot of random jerking around the screen. I'd like the magnifier to just follow the mouse and not jump to the focused element or the text input. Does anyone know of a way of getting GNOME Mag to not follow the text input focus?

Comment: Hi, how did you install gnome-mag? I am trying to but can't figure out how, in 18.04

Comment: I was on an earlier version. I'd recommend checking the universal access menu to see if you can turn it on.

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution to this on my own. In `gsettings`, there are settings under **Gnome > Desktop > a11y > Magnifier** that aren't on the default settings panel in Universal Access.

There are two settings, follow focus and follow carot, that I changed to resolve this issue. You can use `dconf-editor` to edit these settings.